# Thymeleaf - Error displaying list/collection fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am converting a document that is readonly into a one where a user can edit.
Looping the values into a text was possible, *my problem is converting those text into fields*.
Currently I have the following code in my [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/), whereby the defectDto is the object I am planning on using to capture the fields.

```
<tr th:each="res, stat : *{response}"  th:object="${defectDto}">
    <td>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{res[__${stat.index}__].defectId}" readonly="true"/>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

The HTML code above results in a processing error, please see image below:

[image]

In Java, I've used the model to bind the list returned (as seen below):

```
model.addAttribute("response", getDefectMessage.getMessage());
```

*getDefectMessage.getMessage()* above is of type [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of DefectDto. The sample data is as seen below (please see image).
[image]

**Being a newbie in [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/), may I please get assistance in rendering the HTML page without any errors. (Thanks in advance).**

Comment: I think the problem is in `<tr th:each="res, stat : *{response}"  th:object="${defectDto}">`. You either use `th:each` or `th:object`, not both. https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration

Comment: @Fullslack.dev I removed th:object, yet the same error persists.

Comment: Can you edit the post to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If not possible, give at least the code for the _defectDto_ object. A public Git repo is also possible.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev, I added an image in which you can get a better understanding of my DTO class.

Comment: It is difficult to see what you actually want, but here is a wild guess: try `th:each="res, stat : ${defectDto}"` and `th:field="${res.defectId}"`. Limited code is limited answers...

Comment: @Fullslack.dev I've tried that, it results in a error too.

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't work. However without any more code it is hard to figure anything out. For instance the error shown is being thrown on line 23 of _defect_details_, but without seeing that complete code I have no idea what is happening.